# AngularJS Navbar href linking

Tags: html, css, angularjs

My current project has 5 webpages which all have a navbar at the top. I'm now on my AngularJS page and have managed to create a navbar identically to the ones on the other pages, i got it so that when i click on "Home" it displays a message on the right saying "Go To Home" and the home is .p1 b{} styled to look like a box.

I want to be able then click on the styled .p1 b{} displayed to the right of my navbar to  jump onto whichever page out of my navbar was selected.

So if it was About on the navbar i clicked, then i want to click on the styled .p1 b{} about then it link me to my about.html page. Or if it was contact on my navbar i click i would want it to go to my contact.html etc.

Now I can seem to work out the best way include these hrefs to my page. I've tried replacing the # in the div1 nav classes but no luck. Please advise how this can be achieved.

HTML:

```
div" id="Div1" data-ng-app style>
<nav class="{{active}}" data-ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">
<a1 href="#" class="home" data-ng-click="active='home'">Home</a1>
<a1 href="#" class="about" data-ng-click="active='about'">About</a1>  
<a1 href="#" class="javascript" data-ng-click="active='javascript'">
 <a1 href="#" class="angularjs" data-ng-click="active='angularjs'">
 AngularJS</a1>
 <a1 href="#" class="contact" data-ng-click="active='contact'">
 Contact</a1> </nav>
    <p1 data-ng-hide="active">AngularJS NavBar</p1>
    <p1 data-ng-show="active">Go To <b>{{active}}</b></p1>  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 nav{

 display:inline-block;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 background: #323232;
 opacity:0.75;
 box-shadow:0 1px 1px #ccc;
 border-radius:2px;

 }

nav a1{
display:inline-block;
padding: 18px 30px;
color:#fff !important;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
text-decoration:none !important;
line-height:1;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color:transparent;

-webkit-transition:background-color 0.25s;
-moz-transition:background-color 0.25s;
transition:background-color 0.25s;

}

nav a1:first-child{
border-radius:2px 0 0 2px;

}

nav a1:last-child{
border-radius:0 2px 2px 0;

}

nav.home .home,
nav.about .about,
nav.javascript .javascript,
nav.contact .contact,
nav.angularjs .angularjs{
background-color:#e35885;

p1{
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#7d9098;
}

p1 b{
color:#ffffff;
display:inline-block;
padding:5px 10px;
background-color:#c4d7e0;
border-radius:2px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:18px;
}

 #Div1 {
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;



 }
```